# Kohana Routes and Pagination

Tags: pagination, routes, kohana

I'm using Kohana 3.3 and have the following directory structure setup (+ sign means a folder, • means a file):

```
+ modules
  + app-admin
    + classes
      + admin
        • Companies.php
        • Users.php
        • Locations.php
    + i18n
    + views
  + app-front
    + classes
    + i18n
    + views
```

For "app-admin" module I have following routes defined:

```
Route::set('admin default', 'admin')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'  => 'admin',
        'controller' => 'authentication',
        'action'     => 'login'
    ));
Route::set('admin', 'admin/<controller>(/<action>(/<id>))')
->defaults(array(
    'directory'  => 'admin'
));
```

These routes enable me to access "admin" controllers as such:

```
http://localhost/admin/companies
http://localhost/admin/companies/edit/2
http://localhost/admin/companies/add
```

This works with no issue. I installed a pagination module (https://github.com/webking/kohana-pagination) which has following config:

```
'admin' => array(
        'current_page'      => array('source' => 'query_string', 'key' => 'page'), // source: "query_string" or "route"
        'total_items'       => 0,
        'items_per_page'    => 2,
        'view'              => 'admin/_partials/pagination',
        'auto_hide'         => FALSE,
        'first_page_in_url' => FALSE,
    )
```

When I do this, I'm getting following error:

```
Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: Required route parameter not passed: controller
SYSPATH\classes\Kohana\Route.php [ 599 ]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Z

Comment: What URL is the pagination trying to call? Have you tried adding a default controller to you admin route?

Comment: All pagination is doing is just adding "page=x" to the query string, so if the URL is http://localhost/admin/locations, then the pagination will have "http://localhost/admin/locations?page=2".

Comment: Does `localhost/admin/locations` work, and `localhost/admin/locations?page=2` fail?

Comment: Both of these links work with no issue, but when the pagination links are rendered, they "lose" the controller, so instead of having localhost/admin/locations?page=2 I have localhost/admin?page=2

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting up a route specifically for each controller in the "admin" module and provided a default "controller" value as such:

```
Route::set('admin users', 'admin/users(/<action>(/<id>))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'  => 'admin',
        'controller' => 'users', // Provided a default value for <controller>
        'action'     => 'index'
    ));
```

And it did the job, the pagination is working ok now. I thought a "catch-all" route for "admin" would do this for me.